# MVC and opening file

Tags: php, file, url-routing, constants

I have a normal setup for MVC: domain.com/{controller}/{method}/{param}.

I have these 2 functions, the first works and the other one doesn't:

```
private function _getUserWords()
{
    return file(URL . 'public/txt/words.txt');
}

private function _getUserSentences()
{
    $file = URL . 'public/txt/' . strtolower($this->view->randomWord) . '.txt';
    echo $file;
    return file($file);
}
```

Now the first one actually includes the file, but using the second one, it trys to include the 'public' controller and execute the 'txt' method. I can't seem to figure out why this is, any ideas?

Comment: How are you calling these functions?

Comment: I just figured it out after literally hours, it turns out the randomWord had a space after it that I had to trim off. Thanks for interest!